# Changed name of subdirectory - creating pages doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I tried to change my WP subdirectory from www.example.com/test to www.example.com/live, and frontpage and login works as it should. But when I try to access former articles or pages, or create new I just get a 404 error.

*E.g www.example.com/live/my-first-article gives 404, then redirects to frontpage (www.example.com).*

I've defined the site URL and home URL in wp-config, changed the name of the folder, and changed "test" to "live" everywhere in the database.

Anyone have an idea or encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely your .htaccess file which isnt updated. You can update it by going to

> Settings > Permalinks > Save Changes